# maximum connected component in matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

Somebody please help me find the maximum (longest) connected component (not diagonally, only bottom, top, left and right) in a matrix. My code does not work, I have been tying to solve this problem for 24 hours.

For first version:
What's idea? For example, take one element with value '1' and change its value to '2' and look for the other '1' around. Change their ('1' around) value to 3. Take one elem with value '3', look for '1' around, change '1' to '4', etc. All elements > 1 are calculated (l) and compared with the intermediate value of the largest component (comps[u], comps[1] for initial '1').

```
import random

n = int(input())
m = int(input())

#create and output matrix with elems 1-4

a = [[0]*(m+2) for i in range(n+2)]
b = [[0]*(m+2) for i in range(n+2)]

for i in range(n+2):
    for j in range(m+2):
        if i == 0 or i == n+1 or j == 0 or j == m+1:
            a[i][j] = -100 
for i in range(1, n+1):
    for j in range(1, m+1):
        s = random.randint(1, 4)
        a[i][j] = s

for i in range(1, n+1):
    for j in range(1, m+1):
        print(a[i][j], end = " ")
    print()


comps = [0]*5 #counter of longest components
u = 1  #it is value of the elem, adjacent elems whith which we well check

def main(u):
    if u == 5: return()
    global a
    global b
    k = 0
    l = 0
    global m
    global n
    global comps
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        for j in range(1, m+1):
            if a[i][j] == u and k == 0:
                b[i][j] = 2
                k+=1

            elif a[i][j] == u:
                b[i][j] = 1
                k+=1

    w = m//2
    v = n//2
    #a[v][w] = u
    #b[v][w] = 2
    p = True
    c = 2
    while p:
        for h in range(1, n+1):
            for hh in range(1, m+1):
                    if b[h][hh] == c and b[h-1][hh] == 1:
                        b[h-1][hh] = c+1
                        c += 1
                    if b[h][hh] == c and b[h+1][hh] == 1:
                        b[h+1][hh] = c+1
                        c += 1
                    if b[h][hh] == c and b[h][hh-1] == 1:
                        b[h][hh-1] = c+1
                        c += 1
                    if b[h][hh] == c and b[h][hh+1] == 1:
                        b[h][hh+1] = c+1
                        c += 1
                    else:
                        b[h][hh] = 2
                    if c not in b:
                        p = False
                        break
    for x in range(1, n+1):
        for y in range(1, m+1):
            if b[x][y] > 1:
                l += 1
                b[x][y] = 0
                a[x][y] = 0
    if l > comps[u]:comps[u] = l
    if k == l:
        u+=1
    main(u)

main(u)   

maxk = max(comps)
for i in range(1,5):
    if comps[i] == maxk:
        print('The length of the longest con. comp. for digit ', i, ' is ', comps[i])
```

And second version with recursion, it's does not work either.

```
import random

n = int(input())
m = int(input())

a = [[0]*(m+2) for i in range(n+2)]
b = [[0]*(m+2) for i in range(n+2)]

def deep_find(q, o):
    global b
    global ww
    ww += 1
    t = q
    d = o
    b[t][d] = 0
    if t <= n and b[t+1][d] == 1:
        deep_find(t+1, d)
    if t >= 1 and b[t-1][d] == 1:
        deep_find(t-1, d)
    if d<= m and b[t][d+1] == 1:
        deep_find(t, d+1)
    if d>= 1 and b[t][d-1] == 1:
        deep_find(t, d-1)
    print(ww)
    return()


for i in range(n+2):
    for j in range(m+2):
        if i == 0 or i == n+1 or j == 0 or j == m+1:
            a[i][j] = -100
for i in range(1, n+1):
    for j in range(1, m+1):
        s = random.randint(1, 4)
        a[i][j] = s

for i in range(1, n+1):
    for j in range(1, m+1):
        print(a[i][j], end = " ")
    print()

comps = [0]*5
u = 1
while u!=5:
    k = 0
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        for j in range(1, m+1):
            if a[i][j] == u:
                b[i][j] = 1
                k+=1
    p = True
    while p:
        for i in range(1, n+1):
            for j in range(1, m+1):
                if b[i][j] == 1:
                    t = i
                    d = j
                    ww = 0
                    deep_find(t, d)
                    p = False
                    break

    if ww>comps[u]: comps[u] = ww
    if ww == k: u += 1

maxk = max(comps)
for i in range(1,5):
    if comps[i] == maxk:
        print( i, comps[i])
```

Comment: Could you please provide the full statement of your problem, especially the definition of connected component?

Comment: I'll try. Сonnected component -- identical adjacent elements (horizontally and vertically), I need to find the longest one. for example (here the length of the maximum component is 4 for the number '2')
[[2002],   
[2063],  
[2258]]

Comment: Ok, now I understand your problem. First of all, are you familiar with an undirected graph concept? Do you know how to find a size of the biggest connected component in an undirected graph?

Comment: What is the "length" of a connected component that doesn't look like a path, like [1,1,1][0,1,1,],[1,1,1]?

Comment: Sounds like an NP-hard problem, like [longest path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem)